# function upon function in OCaml Confusion about the books's example (beginner)

Tags: function, ocaml

```html
# let rec map1 f l = match l with   
  []->[]
  |h::t -> f h::map1 f t;;
val map1 : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

I am new to OCaml , I have two questions:

1. In the third line, why there is a f before `h :: map1 f t`?  f should be a argument in the `map1` function. Why the book's example puts it seperately?
2. In the first example `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>`  why there is a b list?
   the book explains that b list is the result of the function `f` and a list is the argument of the function `f`. However,  why there is no `a`, `b` list in the following example? It also has a function `f` and it also puts `f` separately in the third line.

```html
# let rec apply f n x=
  if n = 0 then x
  else f ( apply f (n-1) x);;
val apply : ('a -> 'a) -> int -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
|h::t -> f h::map1 f t
```

the precedence rules of Ocaml's syntax means that the above match clause is parsed as

```
|h::t -> (f h)::(map1 f t)
```

and of course `f h`  is the application of function `f` to argument `h`

In words, when the list `l` is matching the pattern `h::t`  (so `l` is a proper list of head `h`  and tail `t`), a pair is *made* `::` (or built, or constructed) of head `f h` and tail `map1 f t`

A typical use would be first to have a function from integers to strings:

```
let nextasstr n = Printf.sprintf "(%d)" (n+1);;
```

So `nextasstr 2` is the string `"(3)"` without the quotes. Of course `[2;3]` is a list of integers, i.e. a `int list`

Then `map1 nextasstr [2;3]` is evaluated to `[ "(3)"; "(4)" ]`, a list of strings, i.e. a `string list`; you see that the second argument has a type different of the result. (this should give an insight on the `'a list` vs `'b list` difference and the typing 
 `map1 : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`) with the first argument being a *arbitrary* function of type `'a -> 'b`

You should see the [Ocaml MOOC](https://www.france-universite-numerique-mooc.fr/courses/parisdiderot/56002/session01/about), follow the [Ocaml tutorial](http://ocaml.org/learn/), read its [documentations](http://ocaml.org/docs/). This may take weeks of work.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question: Why there are two type of lists in the first example?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot teach you all of Ocaml in a few minutes. And I don't see two *types* of lists in the first example (remember that *type* has a very precise meaning, notably for Ocaml)

Comment: One list is an argument to `map1`, the other the result of `map1`.

Comment: @SteveVinoski why there is no 'b' list  to store the result of 'apply'  in the example2?

Comment: Don't think of *storing* (that is *mutating*) data; think of *constructing* data (which is often *immutable*)

Comment: @overloading: unlike `map1` there's nothing specifically creating or operating on lists in example2. The `apply` function applies `f` to `x`, and since `f` takes an `'a` and returns an `'a`, so does `apply`. You could pass a list as the final argument to `apply`, for example, `apply (fun x -> List.map (fun v -> 3*v) x) 5 [1;2;3;4];;` but there's nothing about `apply` that pertains specifically to lists.